# Azure Blob Storage - Set an alert when a new file is uploaded to a specific folder in a blob container

Tags: azure, azure-storage

In Azure, I have a Storage Account that I use to upload files from an IoT device. The files are sent when the IoT device detects certain conditions. All the files are uploaded to the same Blob Container and in the same folder (inside the Blob container).

What I would like to do is to send an email automatically (as an alert) when a new file is uploaded to the Blob Container. I have checked the different options that are provided by Azure to set alerts in Storage accounts (in Azure Portal) but I have not found anything useful.

How could I create this kind of alert?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the azure provides the azure function or webjobs which could be triggered when the new files uploaded to the special container.

I suggest you could use azure function blob trigger to achieve your requirement.
More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob).

In the azure function blob trigger fired method you could also bind [sendgrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid) to send the email.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

Notice: I used C# azure function as example, you could also use another language.

1.Create a blob trigger azure function.

[image]

2.Create a sendgrid([Link](https://app.sendgrid.com/)) account and create API key.

[image]

3.Create set the created azure function sendgrid outbind.

[image]

[image]

4.Add below codes to azure function run.csx.

```
#r "SendGrid"
using System;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;



public static Mail Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    var  message = new Mail
    {        
        Subject = "Azure news"          
    };

    var personalization = new Personalization();
    personalization.AddTo(new Email("sendto email address"));   

    Content content = new Content
    {
        Type = "text/plain",
        Value = name
    };
    message.AddContent(content);
    message.AddPersonalization(personalization);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brando. This is exactly what I needed. I'll try to set the alert that way.